# Unexpected use of 'event' no-restricted-globals - redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I created a calculator in react along with redux. The application works correctly on codepen - link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-calculator-lq90j?file=/src/reducers/reducers.js

When I created a new application on my computer and copied the code from codepen, an error appeared: Unexpected use of 'event' no-restricted-globals. The event variable corresponds to the button clicked. How can they pass the event variable to redux?

Code:

App.js

```
import React from "react";

import Calc from "./Calc";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Calc />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Calc.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { addToMemory } from "./action/action";
import { clear } from "./action/action";
import { addition } from "./action/action";
import { subtraction } from "./action/action";
import { multiplication } from "./action/action";
import { divide } from "./action/action";
import { calculation } from "./action/action";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const getResult = store => store.result;

class Calc extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button id="1" onClick={this.props.addToMemory}>
          1
        </button>
        <button id="2" onClick={this.props.addToMemory}>
          2
        </button>
        <button id="3" onClick={this.props.addToMemory}>
          3
        </button>
        <button id="4" onClick={this.props.addToMemory}>
          4
        </button>
        <button id="5" onClick={this.props.addToMemory}>
          5
        </button>
        <button id="6" onClick={this.props.addToMemory}>
          6
        </button>
        <button id="7" onClick={this.props.addToMemory}>
          7
        </button>
        <button id="8" onClick={this.props.addToMemory}>
          8
        </button>
        <button id="9" onClick={this.props.addToMemory}>
          9
        </button>
        <button
          id="0"
          onClick={this.props.addToMemory}
          disabled={!this.props.result ? true : false}
        >
          0
        </button>
        <button id="." onClick={this.props.addToMemory}>
          .
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.props.addition}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.props.subtraction}>-</button>
        <button onClick={this.props.multiplication}>*</button>
        <button onClick={this.props.divide}>/</button>
        <button onClick={this.props.clear}>Clear</button>
        <button onClick={this.props.calculation}>=</button>
        <div>RESULT: {this.props.result}</div>
        <div>PREV: {this.props.prev}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addToMemory: result => dispatch(addToMemory(result)),
  clear: () => dispatch(clear()),
  addition: () => dispatch(addition()),
  subtraction: () => dispatch(subtraction()),
  multiplication: () => dispatch(multiplication()),
  divide: () => dispatch(divide()),
  calculation: () => dispatch(calculation())
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    result: state.result,
    prev: state.prev
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Calc);
```

reducers.js

```
import { ADD_TO_MEMORY } from "../action/action";
import { CLEAR } from "../action/action";
import { ADD } from "..//action/action";
import { SUB } from "..//action/action";
import { MULT } from "..//action/action";
import { DIV } from "..//action/action";
import { CALCULATION } from "../action/action";

let initialState = {
  prev: "",
  result: "",
  current: "",
  action: ""
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_MEMORY: {
      let id = event.target.id;
      state.result += id;

      return {
        ...state
      };
    }

    case CLEAR: {
      state.result = "";

      return {
        ...state
      };
    }

    case ADD: {
      state.prev = state.result;
      state.result = "";
      state.action = "add";

      return {
        ...state
      };
    }

    case SUB: {
      state.prev = state.result;
      state.result = "";
      state.action = "sub";

      return {
        ...state
      };
    }

    case MULT: {
      state.prev = state.result;
      state.result = "";
      state.action = "mult";

      return {
        ...state
      };
    }

    case DIV: {
      state.prev = state.result;
      state.result = "";
      state.action = "div";

      return {
        ...state
      };
    }

    case CALCULATION: {
      if (state.action == "add") {
        state.current = state.prev;
        state.result = parseFloat(state.result) + parseFloat(state.current);
      } else if (state.action == "sub") {
        state.current = state.prev;
        state.result = parseFloat(state.prev) - parseFloat(state.result);
      } else if (state.action == "mult") {
        state.current = state.prev;
        state.result = parseFloat(state.result) * parseFloat(state.prev);
      } else if (state.action == "div") {
        state.current = state.prev;
        state.result = parseFloat(state.prev) / parseFloat(state.result);
      }

      return {
        ...state
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

action.js

```
export const ADD_TO_MEMORY = "ADD_TO_MEMORY";
export const CLEAR = "CLEAR";
export const ADD = "ADD";
export const SUB = "SUB";
export const MULT = "MULT";
export const DIV = "DIV";
export const CALCULATION = "CALCULATION";

export const addToMemory = event => ({
  type: ADD_TO_MEMORY,
  result: event
});

export const clear = () => ({
  type: CLEAR
});

export const addition = () => ({
  type: ADD
});

export const subtraction = () => ({
  type: SUB
});

export const multiplication = () => ({
  type: MULT
});

export const divide = () => ({
  type: DIV
});

export const calculation = action => ({
  type: CALCULATION,
  action: action
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the action creator `addToMemory` you put the `event` into the `result` attribute of the action.
So your reducer should be changed to:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_MEMORY: {
      let id = action.result.target.id;
      state.result += id;

      return {
        ...state
      };
    }
...
}
```